# Do projections of convex sets equal (up to an affine transformation) some intersection with a hyperplane?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, affine-geometry, projection, rigid-transformation

Let $C$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $C'$ its projection into a k-subspace $H\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for $k\leq n.$ We can suppose for simplicity $p\colon\mathbb{R}^{n-k}\times\mathbb{R}^{k}\to\mathbb{R}^{k},(x,y)\mapsto y$ with $p(C)=C'.$ Does there exist in general a k-plane $H'\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $C'$ is affinely (or rigidly, that is, after a rigid transformation) equivalent to $H'\cap C$?

Comment: I still think my answer does not fully answer your question. Perhaps it would be interesting to find some polytope with a planar projection a polygon with $m$ vertices, but not section of it a polygon with $m$ vertices.

Comment: I am trying to understand better your question. It seems to be: is it true that a shadow of a convex set is in fact the shadow of a plane section of it? In the example below the answer is no for certain shadows, while for other it's yes. Would be interesting to find a set such that it's no for all the shadows....But maybe this is true for a "generic" convex body.

Comment: @orangeskid First of all thanks a lot for your answer and interest. The question is right as you write it but just remember that I speak of k-planes (I do not restrict to dimension 2) and that I allow some transformations to happen so it is more like "...in fact the shadow of a $k$-plane section of it after any of the allowed transformations?" I certainly have no examples. Maybe it helps to mention that my main interest are actually not just convex sets but rigidly convex ones (coming from polynomials with only real zeros on any line through the origin).

Comment: you are very welcome! Can you recommend a good source for reading about rigidly convex sets?

Comment: The best place to begin it is maybe this survey and the references therein: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~helton/BILLSPAPERSscanned/HNpreptA.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always. Think of a thinly cut slanted piece of salami. Some projection of it will be a disk, but there may be no slice of it that is a disk.

${\bf Added:}$ Here is a better example. Consider the intersection of two cylinders

[image]

The projection of one of the blue pieces on a plane perpendicular to an axis of one of the cylinders is a disk. However, no plane section of such a piece is an ellipse.